# Instance member 'jpegData' cannot be used on type 'UIImage'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Tags: xcode, uiimage, jpeg, uid

I have two errors here.
I have tried all the recommended options but still not working!
pls baby steps

```
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { user, error in

        if  error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        let uid = user?.uid
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://instagramclone-fc544.appspot.com").child("profile_image").child(uid!)
        if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = UIImage.jpegData(profileImg, 0.1) {
            storageRef.put(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                self.setUserInfomation(profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl!, username: self.usernameTextField.text!, email: self.emailTextField.text!, uid: uid!)
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: Add implementation for 'Auth.auth().createUser...'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the implementation for the `Auth.auth().createUser...` in the question.

For `Instance member 'jpegData' cannot be used on type 'UIImage'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?` error you need to call the jpegData with the object of UIImage.

For Example, if your image object name is selectedImage then

```
let imageData = selectedImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)
```

This will return the compressed image data with the compression ratio of 0.1

Hope this helps.